# Com qual linguagem posso fazer um formulário?

Tags: java

Preciso fazer um formulário parecido com esse, até mesmo os campos e os (|**|**|__|). E eu estava usando o Java no NetBeans, porém não consigo fazer idêntico a esses campos. Qual linguagem vocês me recomendam para montar um form desses?

Aguardo resposta.

[image: MODELO]

Comment: Procure por Ireport, este framework vai te ajudar para isso

Comment: Eu nunca trabalhei com Java, essa vai ser a primeira vez. Tem como você me orientar melhor como isso funciona?

Comment: Então, eu aprendi fazendo pesquisas, sabe, fui criando meu próprio método de trabalho para diagramar, vc deve desenhar o formulário e depois preencher os dados.

Comment: @Macario1983 Bom dia! Ainda não consegui entender como funciona esse Ireport. Tem algum artigo que explique bem e que possa me indicar?

Comment: Eu estava até tentando redigir um artigo pequeno para poder te ajudar, mas eu perdi o meu manual que criei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu recomendaria usar JavaFX e SceneBuilder, e pra fazer qualquer efeito você pode usar o CSS ( o javafx usa um css proprio ).

Tenho um link de como usar no NetBeans, está em inglês mas tem muitas imagens e é bem fácil : [SceneBuilder no NetBeans](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/use_java_ides/sb-with-nb.htm)

No entanto , você pode fazer esse formulário em qualquer linguagem, mas leve em conta o custo benefício de tempo gasto pra fazer e pra aprender a usar.

Comment: Rodrigo, obrigada pelas dicas! Eu estou estudando Java para o desenvolvimento desse formulário, pois é uma linguagem que eu não entendo bem. Eu até preferiria fazer em php, mas não tenho uma base de formulário em php que eu possa fazer. Contudo, recorri ao Java.